# List of Web.Ui.Controls to apply Style on in one method

Tags: c#, extension-methods, asp.net-4.0, web-deployment

i have a Helper Class that i use for few tasks , one of them is applying style to given control

one of the methods for example is hiding via `Style.Add()`

so for each element i frequently use say a Label

```
Class Attrib
{
        public static void Atdd(Label LBLID, string prop, string value)
        {
            LBLID.Style.Add(prop, value);
        }
}
```

then using the above as template :

```
public Class Hide
{
        public static void LBL(Label LBLID)
        {
            Attrib.Atdd(LBLID, Props.propVisibility, Props.valHidden);
        }
}
```

a class that stores all constants for properties and values

```
    public static class Props
    {
        public const string propVisibility = "visibility", valVisible = "visible", valHidden = "hidden"
    }
```

*the Whole purpose of this effort is ease of use along with having anything needed to be done 
via IntelliSense .

so when ever needed to apply a "Hide" effect i just do

```
Hide.LBL(MyLabelid);
```

- **my Question is :**

How do i make it work for any `Web.UI.WebControl` as parameter to be accepted by 
the Hide method ?

so instead of specifying control type :

```
Hide.LBL(MyLabelid);
```

i will have only one method for all controls

```
Hide.Acontrol(AnyWebControlHere);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i tested . it is working with Common WebControls as one method .

```
        public static void Atdd(Control htmlOrWebCntrl, string prop, string value)
        {
            if (htmlOrWebCntrl.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(WebControl)))
            {
                WebControl wc = htmlOrWebCntrl as WebControl;
                wc.Style.Add(prop, value);
            }
            else
                if (htmlOrWebCntrl.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(HtmlControl)))
                {

                    HtmlControl HtmlCtrl = htmlOrWebCntrl as HtmlControl;

                    HtmlCtrl.Style.Add(prop, value);
                }

        }
```